# RSA decryption is slow for list of messages

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have a chat app, I encrypted the chat messages with RSA algorithm.

Everything works well while chatting. But problem is when the app starts and a list of messages for a couple of users gets loaded. Here is very slow.

1. Number of users: **30 - 40**
2. Number of Messages per user : **40**

I have two nested loops

1. first loop for iterating users
2. second loop for iterating messages for every user

I just decrypt the messages within the nested loop, but loading is very slow.

It takes almost 20 - 25 seconds for loading messages for all users. Also I have tried the Hybrid Cryptography (RSA + AES), but it was also very slow as I was encrypting every message with new secret key in AES, and then encrypting every secret key with PublicKey.

Any suggestions for improvement?

#### AES Key Generation

```
SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
byte [] key = new byte [16];
rnd.nextBytes(key);
this.secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm);
this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.secretKey);
this.cipher.doFinal(input)
```

#### RSA Key Generation

```
 this.keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
 this.keyGen.initialize(1024);
 this.pair = this.keyGen.generateKeyPair();
 this.privateKey = this.pair.getPrivate();
 this.publicKey = this.pair.getPublic();
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell what the problem might be. If you can create a [mcve], please do so and post the code in your question. Just one suggestion: if your code is taking a very long time to generate new random secret keys, perhaps you exhausted the entrpoy pool used to generate random numbers at `/dev/random`. Try using `/dev/urandom` instead.

Comment: @r3mainer You don't need a random number generator for decryption.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes But presumably you do if you're **encrypting every message** with a **new secret key**. Awaiting your suggestions.

Comment: @r3mainer thank you, I just added the part of key generation

Comment: As suggested by @Maarten Bodewes it could be good idea to change from RSA to ECIES. A simple encryption - decryption benchmark showed that the **encryption** time for ECIES is more than 2.5 times higher than RSA, but for **decryption** the time for ECIES is just **half of the time** compared to RSA.

Comment: Firstly, messages should be decrypted on demand and in the background. Secondly, messages should be encrypted and decrypted on the **user's** devices, not your server. That would eliminate the loop over the number of users.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you for suggestions, I am not retrieving from server I am retrieving from local cache also I am using `react-native`, I cant find any background service for IOS

Answer (score 2):

Either use the same symmetric key for multiple messages or use a faster algorithm than RSA for decryption, such as ECIES. You could also see if there is a faster, native implementation available of RSA & AES.

Comment: please see once again as I have added the part of key generating

Comment: Ugh, maybe you could have chosen an example from somebody who can make a normal class design? That's horrific. Class names that are verbs, and many copies of basically `writeToFile`. Yuk!

Comment: thank you, I just extracted some part of them not at all, that is an example I got a help of it as I am not a security programmer, I am just a front-end developer.